# Speed button latest version of video.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, html5-video, video.js

https://github.com/nicetip/videojs-speed

Could anyone help me in using this plugin in latest version of video.js?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is built into the most recent versions of Video.js, so the plugin is unnecessary. Now you can simply pass an array of `playbackRates` in the Video.js configuration and you're good to go. Here's a [working example](http://jsbin.com/vikun/1/edit).

Keep in mind that this only works with the HTML5 playback tech. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

add the option `{ 'playbackRates': [0.7, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0] }`

in script: `videojs('J_video_player', option, function() {})`

or in dom tag: `<video data-setup='{ "playbackRates": [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2] }'></video>`

It's work!