# Set different options for playbackRate for video HTML tag without using JS

Tags: html, html5-video

Is there any way to add 2x speed rate to  HTML tag **without using JS**?
Is it possible to add any special property or attribute to have two different playbackRate  for the client side?

Thanks

```
<div>
    <video controls="" class="-fullwidth">
        <source src="/cms/_4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't believe this is possible without JavaScript. You can change the playback speed of a video in the chrome developer tools, but this is still JavaScript as seen [here](https://blog.somewhatabstract.com/2019/11/18/video-playback-rate-hackery/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is solved by using videojs player.
It has a property that we could add in a video tag to enable us to change the playback rate.
this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45010663/12129650) has a good example about it.

thanks.

Comment: Technically still uses JavaScript though.